# Restore Fedora 34 Repositories Files or Urls

Tags: fedora, repository

I accidentally cleansed the repolist even officials one. Want to have those back cause can't use dnf to install or update the packages. Please help

Comment: Would this help? https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/repositories/. In the worst case, you could install Fedora on a different computer or VM and check.

Comment: Didn't solve bro Think need to undergo installation

Comment: **Fedora 34** → (/etc/)yum.repos.d/{7 files} → `fc34-yum.repos.d.tar.gz` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vfkG3hLHKLHKvp33pKBgZLJC-r0Qna9B/view?usp=sharing → → cd /etc/ ; # tar xvf fc34-yum.repos.d.tar.gz

Comment: Larsen you saved the day man.